# Persisting a new user via RESTful API when using Keycloak User Storage SPI

Tags: java, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I'm implementing a custom user storage by utilising Keycloak's User Storage SPI. In other words, I want Keycloak's functionality without it actually storing the users.

The `UserRegistrationProvider` interface has two methods that need to be implemented if this custom storage provider is supposed to be able to also created and remove users. These methods are `addUser` and `removeUser`, respectively. The `addUser` method in its signature only has a `username` attribute, regardless of what's being sent from the registration form.

There's an official Keycloak example in which the provider is able to directly persist the new user via JPA.

However, in my case I'm relying on my REST API to interact with the backend database. The problem is, I still don't know from where I'm supposed to make this REST call:

- it can't be done from within the `addUser` method, as here only the `username` attribute is available
- in the chain of subsequent method calls other attributes are being attached to the `UserModel` object being returned by the `addUser` method. Apparently, Keycloak does its "magic" internally, ie. not within a method that could potentially be overridden in order to include my REST call (with all attributes present on the object).

Someone who knows Keycloak well should be at least be able to point me in the right direction or tell me that what I want is impossible (which I find hard to believe).